# Datatable refresh not working if page state is true

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have data table which is saving current page state.

```
var tbl = $('#datatable').dataTable({
  "bStateSave": true,
  "fnStateSave": function(oSettings, oData) {
    localStorage.setItem('datatable', JSON.stringify(oData));
  },
  "fnStateLoad": function(oSettings) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('datatable'));
  },
  "order": [
    [6, "desc"]
  ],
  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": [6],
    "visible": false,
    "searchable": false
  }]
});
```

I refreshed my page.It's not refreshing because I saved page state.
I searched by using search box and refreshed it.Still not working.

I have 10 pages. for each raw I have inner page. If I want to see some data from 4th page's inner page, and coming back to the list page I need to save the page state.

Please suggest to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#<%=anchrefrsh.ClientID%>').click(function () {
  location.reload();
  var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
  table.state.clear();
  table.fnDestroy();
  table = $("#datatable").dataTable();
  table.fnDraw();
  return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar implementation in one of my projects.

I used Datatable ajax reload with

```
resetPaging=true & resetPaging=false
```

options as per my requirements. Here is the link for the same.

https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Hope this helps!